# Can someone help me to understand this for-loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I went through some computer science tests and don't understand the outcome of this for-loop.

```java
    int a, b, counter;

    for (a = 1; a <= 10 ; a = a + 1)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < a; b = b + 1) 
        {
                    counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
```

The first for-loop iterates 10 times but what about the second one? And why is the output 55?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger or printing? What part specifically are you having troubles with?

Comment: Add this to the inner loop: System.out.println( "Counter: " + counter + " A: " + a + " B: " + b );

Comment: For your just deleted question - https://regex101.com/r/ws8W8u/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first loop iterates 10 times. For each of first loop iteration second loop iterates: `1 time`, `2 times`, `3 times` .... `10 times`.

**Explanation:** in the second loop `b` iterates from `0` to less than `a`. When `a` is `1`, it iterates `1 time`. When `a` is `2` the second loop iterates `2 times`, when `a` is `3` the second loop iterates `3 times` and so on.

So the counter value would be: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 .... + 10 = (10 * (10 + 1))/2 = 55`

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop iterates `a` amount of times, so the first time it will loop 1 time and the last time it will iterate 10 times.  The counter increments every time this inner loop will run, so it runs 1 + 2 + ... + 10 = 55 times.

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is as follows:

```
c := 0
for a from 1 to 10:
    for b from 0 to a:
        increment c
print c
```

The inner loop iterates once on its first iteration, twice on its second iteration, and N times on its Nth iteration. This means the number of times c is incremented is `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

In general, the formula is

```
n*(first number + last number)/2
```

So, in this case,

```
10(1 + 10)/2 = 55
```

If you changed the last number to, for example, 13, the code outputs 91. The arithmetic progression is

```
13(1 + 13)/2 = 91
```

Answer (score 0):

> The first for-loop iterates 10 times but what about the second one?

The second loop iterates a variable (`a`) number of times.

> And why is the output 55?

Because that is the result when you add the first ten consecutive integers (starting at 1.)

`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55`